# Powershell - Iterate over a specific nested directory

Tags: powershell, iteration

Let's consider this folder tree,

```
SomeFolder\
    User1\Desktop
    User2\Desktop
    User3\Desktop
    User4\Desktop
    User5\Desktop
    ...
```

Now, my goal is to scan every `\Desktop` folder for a certain type of file. I was able to find how to search for a specific type using [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6), but I can't seems to get the notation for looping through each user and then look on their respective desktop.

Here is my try,

```
for($i=0;$i -le 2;$i++){
    $Files = Get-ChildItem SomeFolder\*\Desktop -Filter *.txt -Recurse
    return $Files
}
```

**Note**

I added a for loop in order to minimize the number of users that would be scan. But it is obviously not working since it just keep running.

**EDIT**

Props to @Vivek Kumar Singh which underlined a problem in my code. My for loop was actually redundant which was making the execution time unnecessarily long. Only calling

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem SomeFolder\*\Desktop -Filter *.txt -Recurse
```

can take time but will work eventually.

Comment: The piece of code `Get-ChildItem SomeFolder\*\Desktop -Filter *.txt -Recurse` is working fine for me. Having a `for` loop to limit the number of users is redundant, since the asterik(`*`) in the path would do a recursive search for all the users. Even if you want to limit the number of users, there are better ways of restricting it rather than using a for loop with a variable(`$i` in this case), which is unused, as in your code.

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh Yes, I think my first try was ok. You actually found my mistake. Doing my for loop is actually redundant and what's causing the problem. I'm re-processing the `Get-ChildItem` more than once which causes it to be really slow. But, it is the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only return the first two results from `Get-ChildItem` you can use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object):

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem SomeFolder\*\Desktop -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Select-Object -First 2
```

This should be quick to run as the list of files isn't enumerated completely by `Get-ChildItem`, the pipeline is aborted after the first two items.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$folder = 'C:\work\SomeFolder'

gci $folder -Directory | %{
    $files = Get-ChildItem "$($_.FullName)\Desktop" -Filter *.txt
    Write-Host "$($_.Name) files"
    $files.FullName
}
```

Comment: I think you've missed the requirement to just filter within the `Desktop` subfolder

Comment: Thanks for your notice. Corrected now.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?  I don't test it.

```
$folders =  Get-ChildItem SomeFolder:\  -Directory -Filter "Desktop*"

foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
$Files = Get-ChildItem SomeFolder:\$folder -Filter *.txt -Recurse

}
```

Comment: Your first line is not returning the expected folders.

Comment: Unless you know your code is correct, writing an answer without even testing it is a bad idea. You've not explained how the code in your answer differs/works, or where any issues were with the code in the question. I would recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer as this will better explain everything your answer is missing.